# Two output split lines python

Tags: python

I want to run a true while loop in first line of output with end=' ' just like this  print('*',end=' ') # this will print '*' in first line of output for ever

and so I want to run this as same as previous line but at second line of my output

like this

// this will run and show at first line

```
while True :
   print('*',end=' ')
```

// this will run and show at second line

```
while True :
   print('$',end=' ')
```

***************************** ...

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ...

for instance

write a program that " print '*' every 3s in first line of output and print '$'
every 5s in second line of output " (at the same time)

How can i do this ?

Comment: Not very clear what is the expected output

Comment: Are you looking for the '\n' special character, which makes a new line?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: without special things you cannot print 1 line and the line below and go back again - you can paint whle lines and clear the screen in between or use a module that facilitates better console printing

Comment: How can i do that with special things ?! What do u mean of special things??

Answer (score 0):

use ``` to mark the beginning/end of your code snippets so it's actually readable.

As the comments mentioned, use `\n` for a new line anywhere. Omitting the end='' parameter will put a new line by default.
Otherwise you can just do an empty `print()` to insert a newline character between your two loops, which does the same as `print("\n", end='')`

Comment: he does not want a newline - he wants to increase 2 lines by 1 char each in a loop wich is not possible solely with prints.